# Returning an exit code from a shell script that was called from inside a perl script

Tags: perl, shell, system, exit

I have a perl script (`verifyCopy.pl`) that uses `system()` to call a shell script (`intercp.sh`).

From inside the shell script, I have set up several exit's with specific exit codes and I'd like to be able to do different things based on which exit code is returned.

I've tried using `$?`, I have tried assigning the value of `system("./intercp.sh")` to a variable then checking the value of that, but the error message is always 0.

Is this because even though something inside the shell script fails, the actual script succeeds in running?

I tried adding a trap in the shell script (ie `trap testexit EXIT`  and `testexit() { exit 222; }` but that didn't work either.

Comment: I'm encountering exactly the same problem today, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

`$?` should catch the exit code from your shell script.

```
$ cat /tmp/test.sh 
#!/bin/sh
exit 2

$ perl -E 'system("/tmp/test.sh"); say $?'
512
```

Remember that `$?` is encoded in the traditional manner, so `$? >> 8` gives the exit code, `$? & 0x7F` gives the signal, and `$? & 0x80` is true if core was dumped. See perlvar for details.

Your problem may be one of several things: maybe your shell script isn't actually exiting with the exit code (maybe you want `set -e`); maybe you have a signal handle for SIGCHLD eating the exit code; etc. Try testing with the extremely simple shell script above to see if its a problem in your perl script or your shell script.

Comment: What version of perl are you using?  I am simply getting -1 from the above code you posted :\

Comment: @Nick: Assuming `bas;h` is a typo, this means your system() call failed. Did you remember to `chmod +x /tmp/test.sh`? Print out `$!` as well, that will tell you why system failed.

Comment: @Nick: I'm using 5.12.4, but (after switching say to print) this would work fine with any perl5, all the way back to an ancient one from the mid-90's.

Comment: yeah, the bas;h was a typo.  Here is what I am running (with the same test.sh file you have above) `$ perl -e 'system("/tmp/test.sh"); print $?'`  It prints "-1"  (I am running perl 5.8 btw)

Comment: @Nick: And what does `print $!` have to say? I think you missed my first comment (or our edits crossed and you didn't see the changes).

Comment: Ah, yes I did miss it.  Sorry :)  I did forget to chmod it, and now it works.  With the simple example working, I troubleshooted a bit more with the actual script and figure out that it wasn't working because I was piping the output of the initial command to a sed to filter out unnecessary lines. (`system("/tmp/test.sh |  sed /^#.*#/d"); print $?`)  So basically it would return the exit code of the sed all the time instead of the initial script. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @Nick, `system("/tmp/test.sh | sed /^#.*#/d")` is the same as `system("/bin/sh", "-c", "/tmp/test.sh | sed /^#.*#/d")`, so you are actually getting the exit status of the shell. Perl doesn't even know that `/tmp/test.sh` was run.

Comment: @Nick: AFAIK, that's how shell pipes work (return code of a pipe is that of the last command in the pipe). In bash you can set pipefail to get a different behavior. I guess you could ask a separate SO question on that (if there isn't one already). Of course, since you're working with perl, just get rid of the sed and do your filtering in perl (changing system to open, or use one of the IPC:: modules).

Comment: I ended up using ${PIPESTATUS[0]} which returned the exit code from the shell script.  Thank you for all the responses!